# updating Gradle won't work at all

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am trying to update Gradle to version 4.1 (or 4.3). As the current version is 2.14.1
I have tried almost everything, but Gradle just won't update. Have checked settings, repository, dependency, etc, all seem as it should. I also tried restarting Android studio. But still getting the: `Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 2.14.1.`

It is driving me insane.

Comment: Did you change the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to `{root}/gradle`
2. Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` file
3. Set your `distributionUrl` to:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
   ```

Comment: Arg, I was looking at the gradle inside the app folder, in the {root}/gradle the distributionUrl was still the old one. Changed it and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to run this command:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.3
```

It will update your gradle wrapper version

**[Update]** If this command doesn't work. Add this block to your build.gradle project level.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = 4.3
}
```

and then run the previous command.

Comment: Tried this and getting the following error: Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'.